# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome shell quadrant tiling

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, tiling

I am looking for a way to perform quadrant window tiling using custom key combinations, similar to how could be accomplished using Compiz before (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> for example).

I've tried ShellTile and gTile and both of these require manual movement of windows, and they lock them to each other but not to a 2x2 grid.

So if anyone has a suggestion on how to do this using Gnome shell on Ubuntu 18.04 I am all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) as it works perfectly for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried x-tile? I use it in Cinnamon to quad tile opened windows with `x-tile q` assigned to a custom shortcut and it works well.